# Python PySide with Qt Designer

Tags: python, qt, qt-creator, pyside

I'm trying to make a PySide application. I've watched some tutorials to try to solve the problem but none worked and i do not have any errors in my code.
Here's the file where i'd do the scripting
main.py

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui  
from ui import Ui_Form

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(QtGui.QMainWindow)
    self.ui = Ui_Form()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__init__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    wid = QtGui.QWidget()
    wid.resize(250, 150)
    wid.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    wid.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: what tutorial ? You create class `Main()` but you don't use it. Maybe you should do `wid = Main()`

Comment: first problem: it has to `"__main__"` in line `if __name__ == '__main__':` . It seems you have to watch all tutorials again.

Comment: still doesn't actually launch anything and Main() is underlined as a error but the Pycharm console doesn't print any errors

Comment: see code in answer

Answer (score 2):

1. It has to be `'__main__'`

   ```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
   ```
2. You have class `Main()` but you don't use it

   ```
   wid = Main()
   ```
3. You have to execute `super()` in correct way

   ```
   super(Main, self).__init__()
   ```
4. BTW: and you have wrong indentions inside class

Working example - without `ui` because I don't have it - but it shows window.

```
from PySide import QtGui  
import sys
#from ui import Ui_Form

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        #self.ui = Ui_Form()
        #self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.resize(250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Simple')
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    wid = Main()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score -1):

Well i just realized that i never actually ran self.show().
Problem solved